# Parameters of Evdev Scrolling Distance: meaning?

Tags: terminal, mouse, xinput

I do not understand the two last parameters of the mouse scrolling distance I would like to increase:

```
xinput list-props 14
sudo xinput set-prop 14 'Evdev Scrolling Distance' 1, 1, 1
```

14 is the device ID in my case (`$ xinput list`).

The first one represents, how many mouse wheel scroll units get counted as one scroll, which means, that if the value was 2, then I would need to move the mouse wheel by two scrolling units in any direction to move the page. This, of course, is recommended to be set to one.

But what do the other two values mean?
Ultimately, **how to I extend the distance of page scroll per mouse wheel movement units?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

from: https://www.mankier.com/4/evdev

> Option "VertScrollDelta" "integer" The amount of motion considered one
>   unit of scrolling vertically. Default: "1".  Property: "Evdev
>   Scrolling Distance".
>
> Option "HorizScrollDelta" "integer" The amount of motion considered
>   one unit of scrolling horizontally. Default: "1".  Property: "Evdev
>   Scrolling Distance".
>
> Option "DialDelta" "integer" The amount of motion considered one unit
>   of turning the dial.  Default: "1". Property: "Evdev Scrolling
>   Distance".